# One small where query issue in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I am newer to zend Framework and i facing one issue in query, Please help me.

```
 $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
        $syear = date('Y');
        $select->where(array(
        'YEAR(date) = ?' => $syear,
        'user_id = ?' =>$myid,
        )); 
        $select->order('id DESC');
        });
        $counter3= count($rowset);
```

Here, i want count of current year record and userid is fixed like 50 then output is all data with 50  userid and current year

here my year condition in WHERE succesufully work but `'user_id = ?' =>$myid`

it's not working, suppose $myid value is 50 ,

but if i pass 50 value directly like  `'user_id = ?' =>50`  then its working

What is the problem here,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you get your $myid variable? var_dump($myid); exit; it before using the query and try figuring out whats going wrong.

Comment: Thanks For your replay, But var_dump output is `int(50)` but my result is not right its still display 0 user

Comment: Paste assembled query returned by: var_dump($select->__toString());

Comment: To me it looks like the variable is out of scope. You are using a anonymous function so you dont have any access to your prior defined variables. Just add a use (myid) to your function call and it should work.

Comment: $myid is already called from function argument and it's return int(50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am guesting `$myid` is defined before the select function is called. in this case u need to tell your select function to use this variable.

```
$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use($myid) {});
```